# How to index variable character column for pattern matching in Postgres?

Tags: postgresql, indexing, pattern-matching, query-optimization, sql-like

Postgres Version: **9.5.19**

I have the following table containing domains:

```
CREATE TABLE sites (
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  domain character varying(255),
);

-- Indices -------------------------------------------------------

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX sites_pkey ON sites(id int4_ops);
CREATE INDEX index_sites_on_domain ON sites(domain text_ops);
```

```
id | domain
---| -----------
1  | www.abc.com
2  | alpha.net
3  | catfood.xyz
4  | example.org
5  | un.gov
6  | xyz.com
.  | .......
```

The total number of records in the table are near ~ 1 million and running a pattern matching query easily takes 20+ seconds:

```
SELECT * from sites where domain LIKE '%abc.com%
```

I have a normal `btree` index on `domain` but that isn't being used for the above query. `EXPLAIN` shows a sequential scan.

How do I index this column so that the queries are fully optimized?

Comment: Like '%xxx%' doesn't use btree indices.  Like 'xxx%' does.  Consider using pg_trgm as explained here: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/pgtrgm.html

Comment: Is your table named "sites", or is it named "domains"?

Comment: That query easily completes in half a second for me (against sites, not domains) with no index with 1,572,864 rows.  '%un%' is too short to benefit from a trigram index, so if that is a representative query it won't do you much good.

Comment: Updated question with correct table name in query. I agree %un% is too short, however, the actual wildcard patterns we use are longer than this, mostly actual domains, e.g. www.abc.com, www.longls.com, etc. etc.

Comment: I agree with jjanes: 20 seconds to do a full table scan on just one million rows seems rather slow. But a trigram index might help if your search patterns are longer

Comment: I'll accept @BjarniRagnarsson's comment as the answer since adding `pg_trgm` has significantly reduced the query time and has brought it under 100ms

Answer (score 0):

First create an expression index on the domain parts, e.g. turning `'www.abc.com'` to the array `'{www,abc,com}'`.

```sql
CREATE INDEX index_on_domain ON sites USING GIN (regexp_split_to_array(domain, '\.'));
```

Then run a slightly modified query.

```sql
SELECT *
FROM sites
WHERE regexp_split_to_array(domain, '\.') @> '{abc,com}'
  AND domain LIKE '%abc.com%
```

It's definitely uglier than your original query, but it will do the job.

The first condition of the where clause will use the GIN index to reduce the result set dramatically by checking if the domain parts contain the same parts as your query. The second will act as a verifying condition to ensure that `'abc'` is immediately preceding `'com'` but will only be run against rows that match the first, indexed condition. Use GIST (or [GIN with fastupdate](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/gin-implementation.html#GIN-FAST-UPDATE)) instead if the sites table is frequently updated since for v9.5, standard GIN indexes are better for mostly-read-only use cases while GIST has better performance on tables/indexes that are updated regularly.

Trigrams could be used, but they are more useful I think for unstructured text. Domains on the other hand have structure where the parts have distinct (and atomic) meanings. It of course depends upon your use case, but from your description I'm assuming that you aren't looking for results like `'sample.xyzabc.com'` as well. If you are, trigrams may in fact be the way to go since your queries truly are unstructured. If you are actually looking for complete domain parts, splitting the domain and searching by independent cohesive parts will probably give you cleaner results.

Additionally if your query cannot be changed because the code is unmodifiable or generated by a library that is not easily modified, you may have to accept the poor performance of a sequential scan when using open-ended LIKE wildcard patterns as seen here.